What is the average number of questions needed for decision tree
Assume you're using the optimal strategy, where you ask the fewest number of questions to guess the animal from this decision tree. What is the average number of questions you need to ask?

Is there any formula for this?
I was thinking that in my case if I am looking at the left side of the tree I need to ask 2 questions to guess the animal. And if I am looking at the right side of the tree I need to ask 3 questions. Does that mean the average number of questions to ask is 2.5? Am I missing something?

Is each animal equally likely?

Yes, that's right

So there are 2 animals that take 2 questions to reach, and 4 animals that take 3 questions?

Imagine you start with $a$ animals, ask $n$ questions and that each yes answer eliminates exactly half of the animals.
The number of animals eliminated after $n$ questions is then equal to $a\times(\frac{1}{2})^n$.
Now, you want all but one of the animals to be eliminated by your questions, so with $n$ questions you can reduce $a\times(\frac{1}{2})^n+1$ possible animals down to $1$.
For large numbers of animals, the $+1$ is not going to make much of a difference, so to determine the number of questions needed to reduce $a$ down to $1$ we need to solve $a\times(\frac{1}{2})^n=1$ for $n$.
The solution is $n=\log_2{a}$
In the case of your diagram where $a=6$, $n=\log_2{6}\approx 2.6$ which agrees with your estimate.

Oh, I see. Thank you very much!

The main issue with my answer is that it assumes equal numbers are eliminated with Yes as No at each decision point. This may not always be a fair assumption.
